# Origin of the term "Shell Bank"

Tags: banking, terminology

Why are shell banks called "Shell" banks?

I read somewhere it was because of their origin in the Caribbeans but I don't see the link.

Comment: I'm sure it's because it's just a pass through entity, like the shell game/magic trick where most of the shells are empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the Caribbeans...

A "shell" in nature is just a casing - it has no internal substance, but instead covers (or hides) the actual substance or organism.  Think of an egg shell or a conch shell - they have no meaning other than to contain or hide something inside it.

A shell bank is a bank that has no physical presence in any country.  It is an empty entity.  They usually exist only to facilitate money laundering or other nefarious activities for some other entity.

A "shell corporation" or "shell company" is a similar concept - they exist only to hide or protect the *actual* company behind it, typically to avoid taxes.

Answer (score 2):

> Shell bank means “a bank that has no physical presence in the country
>   in which it is incorporated and licensed, and which is unaffiliated
>   with a regulated financial group that is subject to effective
>   consolidated supervision.

[Wolfsberg Anti-Money Laundering Principles for Correspondent Banking](https://docsbay.net/wolfsberg-anti-money-laundering-principles-for-correspondent-banking) by The Wolfsberg Group 2014,*Wolfsberg Correspondent Banking Principles*

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. This is a good answer, but the question already has an accepted answer from 2 years ago.